# Parsing response from Api - Data returned is seen as double and Integer - How to Parse

Tags: android, json, api, parsing

The API returns either a whole number like = 129
or A decimal for example 0.28 
Here is the response from API:

```
"ETH":{"USD":730.06}"
```

I'm trying to parse the JSON
with the following:

```
Double ethPrice = (double) arr.get("USD");
```

Which works if the data returned is a number with a decimal but if it is a whole number then I'm getting:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

I'm not doing any mathematical function with the response, therefore, a string type would work too.

I feel like it is a small problem I should have solved already. But spent a bit of time on it now and don't want to waste anymore. 
Any help would be great.

Edit :

Request code snippet of parsing:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
JSONObject arr = obj.getJSONObject("ETH");
Double ethPrice = (double) arr.get("USD");
```

Where result is a string (inside async task - onPostExecute(String result))

Comment: Try Using float data type .

Comment: How are you parsing?share snippet

Comment: Edited to show parsing

Comment: Which line causes the error? Why are you using mixing `Double` and `double`? I suggest that you learn the difference between wrapper objects and primitive types.

Comment: use `arr.getDouble()`

Comment: Hi @Code-Apprentice. Thanks for the suggestion. I do know the difference. I have sent a snippet of code I was just testing.
TimCastelijns Thats it. Thank you (this is what I call a brain fart)

Comment: This is a good example of where you take some time to look at the Javadoc documentation.

Answer (score 2):

If you sure that you will get `Double`, you can use `arr.getDouble("USD")` instead of `arr.get("USD")`.

Your code will be the next:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
JSONObject arr = obj.getJSONObject("ETH");
Double ethPrice = arr.getDouble("USD");
```